# how to hover the image class specific

Tags: html, css, angular7

```css
img:hover {
  content: url("https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160")
}
```

```html
<img src="https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160" />
```

the above scenario works fine, but I have more than one img in same list and wanted hovering , I have to go for class specific .

```css
img:hover .apple {
  content: url("https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160")
}

img:hover .mango {
  content: url("https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160")
}
```

```html
<img class="apple" src="https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160" />
<img class="mango" src="https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160" />
```

I tried the above sceanrio also tried class specific also but it doesnt work

Comment: img:hover .apple is looking for an element with the apple class under an img tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is provided below :

```
img.apple:hover  {
  content: url("https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160")
}

img.mango:hover  {
  content: url("https://img.tineye.com/result/2aface83405d2b9582aa88c4f1684fc505aed67c1cdcbd158e34f0fcb23060cc?size=160")
}
```